# gulp сборка на веб хост

Tags: javascript, html, gulp, веб-сервер

есть gulp сборка сайта, ее нужно выложить в сеть на хост, загружаю папку build на хост и при открытии сайт/index.html открывается пустая страница, но с нужным названием, что нужно сделать?

Comment: Проверьте ошибки в консоле, возможно нужно установить зависимости.

Comment: Этому вопросу катастрофически не хватает важной информации кроме как "помогите не работает".

Comment: Для начала - надо выбрать веб-сервер.